# Java SocketException Maximum number of datagram sockets reached

Tags: java, udp, multicast, socketexception

I have a `java` app program run on `centos 6.3` and `tomcat 7` as the app container, currently I meet one error : `java.io.socketexception Maximum number of datagram sockets reached`

we use `MulticastSocket` class to send message. when this error happened, I check the current server `UDP socket` count with command: `ss -s`

**Total: 212 (kernel 248)**
TCP:   70 (estab 15, closed 44, orphaned 0, synrecv 0, timewait 40/0), ports 22

```
Transport  Total     IP        IPv6
*          248       -         -        
RAW        0         0         0        
UDP        40        40        0        
TCP        26        26        0        
INET       66        66        0        
FRAG       0         0         0
```

and I also check the

```
ulimits -n
```

The default setting is `32768`, seem UDP socket count not exceed max count.

Any ideas for this error?

Answer (score 1):

> we use `MulticastSocket` class to send message.

Why? You only need a `MulticastSocket` to *receive* multicasts.

Obviously you are leaking `MulticastSockets.` Presumably you are creating a new one per message and never closing it.

Comment: I check the heap dump, don't find lots of lived MulticastSocket instance in the heap,(only 20+ MulticastSocket instance), actually, i don't close the socket, if don't close socket, does this cause socket leaking ??